# Handle html special charcaters in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

My product descriptions in the database have html characters. An example is

`&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;example text&lt;br&gt;&lt;/span&gt;example text.&lt;/p&gt;`

I have done `json_encode` on the product descriptions in the controller and passing the variable to the view.

```
 $data['share_description'] = json_encode($product_info['description']);
```

I want to implement facebook share using javascript jdk for facebook
Parsing the product descriptions has been a challenge and have been able to output the descriptions to the share dialog but they still have html tags on them. Any ideas to get around this problem

This is what i have tried so far

```
 function shareFacebook(){


var currentLocation = window.location.href;
var title = "<?php echo $heading_title ;?>";
var customDescription = "";
var image = "<?php echo $shareImage ;?>";
var str = '<?php echo $share_description ;?>';    
var html = $.parseHTML( str );

console.log(html);

var desc = html[0].data;
var final = desc.replace(/\"/g, "");

FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: currentLocation,
  title:title,
  description:final,
  picture:image,
}, function(response){});
 }//end method shareFacebook
```

Console screen shot

[image: Console]

Comment: console.log(html); can you show any screenshot regarding output

Comment: @KumarRakesh added the screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) do the trick:

```
var q = '&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;example text&lt;br&gt;&lt;/span&gt;example text.&lt;/p&gt;';
var html = $.parseHTML(q);
var text = $(html[0].data).text(); // output: "example textexample text."
```

Runnable example inside snippet below:

```js
var q = '&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;example text&lt;br&gt;&lt;/span&gt;example text.&lt;/p&gt;';
var html = $.parseHTML(q);
var text = $(html[0].data).text();
alert(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry tried that getting Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression erroe

Comment: @kelvindev So you have error in your syntax, or `html[0]` is empty, check if data exist before parse. My solution works, which i prove in runnable snippet

Comment: Also to handle new lines in the descriptions you should do `$data['share_description'] = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $product_info['description']))` otherwise some descriptions will throw errors